# Azure ADF quote all disabled

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

in Azure copy , this option is disabled

Please see image
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5crBb.png

Any pointers

Regards
Ravikiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a work around I added text qualifiers to sink mapping after importing the schema
[Image of the workaround](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28yx8.png)

Answer (score 2):

Quota all text only enabled in Data Flow Sinks settings:
[image]

Ref:

1. [Sink properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#sink-properties)
2. [Sink example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#sink-example)

In Copy active, the the option is disabled, but we could set it in dataset quote char:
[image]

But as you said "it used to work before and suddenly it stopped", If you want get the root cause about the feature, the best way is ask Azure support for help.
Ref: How to [create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I did those changes but my header is not getting text qualified, it used to before suddenly it stopped

Comment: @RaviKiran Yeah,  I agree with you. The quote doesn't work for the header. Any workaround is that using json format first and then convert it to txt/csv. All the field will has quota.

Comment: Thanks , it used to work before and suddenly it stopped, not sure any updates were done internally though

Comment: @RaviKiran You're welcome. If you want get the root cause about the feature, the best way is ask Azure support for help. Ref:[How to create an Azure support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

Comment: @RaviKiran hope my answer will satisfy you. If my answer is helpful for you, can  you accept(mark) it as answer? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you, have a good day!

Comment: As a work around I just tried to add mapping to the sink and added text qualifiers as below